# SVG Xlink won't link to external file with xlink:href in <use> tag

Tags: svg, href, xlink

I have two SVG files. I'm trying to xlink the contents of rect.svg into tst_use.svg. The contents of tst_use.svg are,

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.1" id="svg_hom_img" width="508" height="438">
<use x="0" y="0" id="us_g1_0" width="508" height="438" xlink:href="rect.svg"/>
</svg>
```

and the contents of rect.svg are,

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.1" id="svg_hom_img" width="508" height="438">
<rect x="0" y="1" width="250" height="250" id="BackDrop" pointer-events="all" style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;     stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:0"/>
</svg>
```

Of course, the two files are in the same directory. I have tried a number of combinations. The code works inline. rect.svg displays in the browser. I can also cobble the files together with javascript. Other people use this syntax. Why can't tst_use.svg xlink to rect.svg?

Comment: <use> can't point to a complete file in SVG 1.1, it has to point to something within that file. If you want a complete file use the <image> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using Robert Longson's comment, I changed test_use.svg to,

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0" id="svg_hom_img" width="508" height="438">
  <use x="0" y="0" id="us_g1_0" width="508" height="438" xlink:href="rect.svg#BackDrop"/>
</svg>
```

with the same rect.svg as in the question. That displayed the rectangle in Firefox, but not in Chrome. It seems that javascript is the best solution.